# Having an Identity column in a table with primary key with varchar type

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, guid

I was told to create an `autID` identity column in the table with GUID `varchar(40)` as the primary key and use the `autID` column as a reference key to help in the join process. But is that a good approach?

This causes a lot of problems like this

```
CREATE TABLE OauthClientInfo
(
    autAppID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    strClientID VARCHAR(40),   -- GUID
    strClientSecret VARCHAR(40) 
)

CREATE TABLE OAuth_AuthToken
(
    autID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    strAuthToken VARCHAR(40),
    autAppID_fk INT 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES OauthClientInfo(autAppID)
)
```

I was told that having `autAppID_fk` helps in the joins vs having `strClientID_fk` of `varchar(40)`, but my point to defend is we unnecessarily adding a new id as a reference that some times forces to make joins.

Example, to know what is the `strClientID` that the `strAuthToken` belongs, if we have `strClientID_fk` as the reference key then the `OAuth_AuthToken` table data make sense a lot for me. Please comment your views on this.

Comment: You're putting `GUID`s in a `VARCHAR(40)` column?! Why not use the [proper type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql)?

Comment: @DavidG I initially planned to create a random string using some kind of random generator rather than an GUID. Yes I would have used UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as my datatype(as bill said), the point is if I have my strClientID of varachar(40) or may be even an UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type in my table, having an autID just to help on joins is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

> I was told to create an autID identity column in the table with GUID varchar
>   (40) as the primary key and use the autID column as a reference key to help  in the join process. But is that a good approach?

You were told this by someone that confuses clustering and primary keys. They are not one and the same, despite the confusing implementation of the database engine that "helps" the lazy developer.

You might get arguments about adding an identity column to every table and designating it as the primary key. I'll disagree with all of this. One does not BLINDLY do anything of this type in a schema. You do the proper analysis, identify (and enforce) any natural keys, and then you decide an whether a synthetic key is both useful and needed. And then you determine which columns to use for the clustered index (because you only have one). And then you verify the appropriateness of your decisions based on how efficient and effective your schema is under load by testing. There are no absolute rules about how to implement your schema.

Many of your indexing (and again note - indexing and primary key are completely separate things) choices will be affected by how your tables are updated over time. Do you have hotspots that need to be minimized? Does your table experience lots of random inserts, updates, and deletes over time? Or maybe just lots of inserts but relatively few updates or deletes? These are just some of the factors that guide your decision.

Comment: I completely agree with your comments. But, I don't find any counter reason to not add the Identity column as the joins performs better on this column than my other column with varchar(50). Even though the varchar(50) should be the primary key. We basically are mapping the real primary key to Identity column and using that as a reference key in other tables.

Comment: I agree with the "CheckList".It is also important to note "how GUID" are sorted internally.GUID are not atuo increament type.These factor also help in determinig fill factor and CI

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data type for GUID columns not VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have read, **Auto increment int** is the most suitable column for clustered index.

And `strClientID` is the worst candidate for PK or cluster index.

Most importantly you haven't mention the purpose of `StrClientID`. What kind of data does it hold, how does it get populated?

Comment: StrClientID holds a string of 40 to 50 chars. As this Column has to be referenced in many tables, I created an Identity column and use that as reference in other tables instead of StrClientID.